# Find the number of zeros of $3\sin(100x) +1$ for $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Find the number of zeros of $3\sin(100x) +1$ for $x\in[0,1].$

First observe that it suffices to find the number of zeros for $\sin(y)+ \frac{1}{3}$ for $y\in[0,100]$.

There are two zeros between $\pi$ and $2\pi$, so we have $2*[\frac{100}{2\pi}] = 30$ zeros in $[0, 30\pi]$. Since $ 100-30\pi \approx 5.8 \geq \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$, so we have one more zero.

Is there a good way to show there is no zero in the last part $[31\pi + \frac{\pi}{2},100]$ without using the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to determine whether $\sin(100)$ is greater than or less than $-\frac 13$. We have $32\pi \approx 100.48$, so $\sin(100) \approx \sin(-0.48) \approx -0.48 + \frac 16(0.48)^3 \approx -0.48+0.02=-0.46\lt - \frac 13$, so there is no last zero.  It is between $100$ and $32\pi$.